# devise-two-factor how to get code valid for custom time to send over SMS/Email etc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, two-factor-authentication

I am trying to implement **2FA(two factor authentication)** in my existing `rails 4.2.10` application, I have configured many bits.

Issue I am facing is to get/retrieve a code which is valid for `5 minutes` and send this code over to user on his defined `phone number` or `email`.

*I did tried* ROTP::TOTP.new(user.otp_secret).at(Time.now), guessing from gem's source code, which seems to work fine and give a valid otp_code in console, but in `sessions_controler`, as weird as it sounds, `user.otp_secret` is null, always...

I have posted [an issue on the gem.](https://github.com/tinfoil/devise-two-factor/issues/119)

I don't think this can be bug, rather this is a functionality I want to build.

My stack:
Ruby: 2.4.2
Rails: 4.2.10
Devise: 4
attr_encrypted: 1.4(if it matters)

Additionally, I want to extend drift period(code acceptance time) to 5 minutes. I think that will be easy, but doing it for single code, not universally, or for all codes, this has me thinking for a while now.
*My main issue is the first one, getting the code to send through SMS, this is a subproblem, which I think is doable, but if anyone has/had experience with this and can help, that will be great.*

**UPDATE:** I updated attr_encrypted and restarted the system, it started working, also I realized there is a method `current_otp` in which `devise_two_factor` adds in the user model, so I started using that. **BUT** after a few minutes, it is also throwing the same issue of user.otp_secret being nil. Its getting weird...

**UPDATE 2/Hacky solution:** Weirdly enough, I had to add these 3 methods in user model and everything started working:

```
  def encrypted_otp_secret
    self[:encrypted_otp_secret]
  end

  def encrypted_otp_secret_iv
    self[:encrypted_otp_secret_iv]
  end

  def encrypted_otp_secret_salt
    self[:encrypted_otp_secret_salt]
  end
```

As you can suspect, i got here by examining a behavior thatdoing `user.encrypted_otp_secret` was giving me nil while it was not, even after reloading user model. And doing `user[:encrypted_otp_secret]` was giving me the actual value.

It seems like a bug in attr_encrypted. I am not sure yet.

Comment: What stage in the `sessions_controller` are you trying to call `user.otp_secret`? How are you getting that `user` object?

Comment: @philnash I am in `prepend_before_action` hook on create action, I have a `find_user` method where I look up the user by params[:email] or session saved uid. And I am getting inspiration from https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb#L7 this gitlab controller and related concern to implement 2 step 2FA.

Comment: Restarting the system and updating the attr_encryptor gem seems to have done some magic. Still not sure if this will keep working...

Comment: Hmm... sounds like a bug somewhere! If you could share a bit more of your code that you're using it might be easier to see what is going on.

Comment: There is too much code, I don't know what to share and what not to.. But one thing is for sure, whatever it is its coming from `devise_two_factor` or attr_encrypted(which is included by `devise_two_factor` ).
Intresting thing is that doing `puts "encrypted: #{user.reload.encrypted_otp_secret}"` also reveals nil encrypted_otp_secret, while it is nto true, BECAUSE if i do user[:encrypted_otp_secret] I get it right as it should be!!! This is very weird, and i think this is the key to the issue.

Comment: @philnash Interestingly, if i restart server things start working, and after some time, its all back to same. After a few login and logouts, this behaviour re appears. As I mentioned before this `encrypted_otp_secret` being nil while it is not actually seems the key to the problem because everything is calculated and based on this, when i check in console or access it like `user[:encrypted_otp_secret]` it is there...

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that runs into this issue, I have found a next step needed to get the current_otp method to work. In the method pre_otp method call

```
   > u = User.find_by(email: 'test@example.com')
   > u.otp_required_for_login = true
   > u.otp_secret = User.generate_otp_secret
   > u.save!
```

and then you can call u.current_otp...

https://blog.tommyku.com/blog/integrating-two-step-two-factor-authentication-into-rails-4-project-with-devise/